# find string with format '[number]' using regex

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I have a string in a django/python app and need to search it for every instance of `[x]`. This includes the brackets and x, where x is any number between 1 and several million. I then need to replace x with my own string.

ie, `'Some string [3423] of words and numbers like 9898'` would turn into `'Some string [mycustomtext] of words and numbers like 9898'`

Note only the bracketed number was affected. I am not familiar with regex but think this will do it for me?

Comment: I would prefer not to, but i guess I could deal with that special case individually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex is precisely what you want. It's the re module in Python, you'll want to use re.sub, and it will look something like:

```
newstring = re.sub(r'\[\d+\]', replacement, yourstring)
```

If you need to do a lot of it, consider compiling the regex:

```
myre = re.compile(r'\[\d+\]')
newstring = myre.sub(replacement, yourstring)
```

Edit: **To reuse the number**, use a regex group:

```
newstring = re.sub(r'\[(\d+)\]',r'[mytext, \1]', yourstring)
```

Compilation is still possible too.

Comment: `\d*` matches `zero or more digits`. You probably want `\d+`.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Thanks, well caught.

Comment: @Thomas K, @Frédéric Hamidi. thanks, very helpful. I just realized that my `replacement` should actually be based on the number that is found. ie, if "[2345]" is found i might replace it with something like "[mytext, 2345]". How do I get that found number?

Comment: Define a group within your regex, then refer to it in the replacement string: `re.sub(r'\[(\d+)\]',r'[mytext, \1]', yourstring)`  Compilation should still work too.

Comment: @rsp: OK, it seems that these comment fields can eat backslashes. There should have been some before the square brackets `\\[ \\]`. I've corrected the last example in the main answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re
input = 'Some string [3423] of words and numbers like 9898'
output = re.sub(r'\[[0-9]+]', '[mycustomtext]', input)
# output is now 'Some string [mycustomtext] of words and numbers like 9898'
```

Comment: don't forget there are more than 10 numbers.

Comment: @Keng: What are you talking about?  My code works just fine for multidigit numbers.

Comment: that's true but it only matches numbers with the digits 0-9; there are more than 10 digits. ;o) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/09/86555.aspx          http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html

Comment: @Keng: The choice of whether or not to match Unicode digits depends entirely on the context in which this code will run.  In the first link of yours, Raymond gives a great counterexample of why you *shouldn't* match Unicode digits in some situations.  It depends on what sort of text OP is matching.

Comment: Yep...and we both know Murphy says he'll be choosing it too....lol....and at about 3 o'clock in the morning when the wheels come off the whole thing. 80)

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else is jumping in here I'll give you my non-Python version of the regex

```
\[(\d{1,8})\]
```

Now in the replacement part you can use the 'passive group' $n to replace (where n = the number corresponding to the part in parentheses).  This one would be $1